# Is there a tcl command to start the shell prompt in a script

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script, and at a point of execution and given a condition, I would like the option of starting the prompt (%).

Something like

```
# ... previous program logic
if { some_condition } {
   # start shell prompt within current execution context
}
else 
  # continue execution
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct command to do this. You can look into tclreadline library- this exactly provides the functionality you want

Comment: tkcon works well in this situation, if you're using Tk

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's better to use `tclreadline` package to start a prompt within your script!

something like this :

```
package require tclreadline

# ... previous program logic
if { some_condition } {
   # Start the shell prompt
   set prompt "% "
   while {[gets [tclreadline::readline $prompt] line] != -1} {
      # Handle user input
      # ...
   }
}
else {
  # continue execution
  # ...
}
```

as you see,I first load the `tclreadline` package and if `some_condition` is true, I start a `while` loop that repeatedly prompts the user for input using the `tclreadline::readline` command!

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Tcl itself doesn't provide such a thing (though it does give you the tools for it with `info complete`, etc.) The easiest option might be to use the [`commandloop`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/commandloop) from the TclX package:

```
package require Tclx

if { $some_condition } {
    commandloop
}
```

The linked wiki page has a pure Tcl partial workaround for if you don't mind missing a few of the bells and whistles of the real thing.